# Доступ к классу в загруженном swf

Tags: swf, actionscript-3

Здравствуйте!

Возможно ли получить доступ к уже загруженному классу (загружал не я, я "внедряюсь" через PreloadSwf)? 
Говорит, что *`Variable is not defined`*, хотя даже через монстер дебагер видно, что он загружен, вот мой тестер:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.*;
import  flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

public class PreLoaders extends Sprite
{

    private var loader:LoaderInfo;
    public function PreLoaders():void
    {
        if (stage)
        {
            init();
        }
        else
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }
    }
    private function init(e:Event=null):void
    {

        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        root.addEventListener('allComplete',allCompleteHandler);
    }

    private function allCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        try
        {

            var url:String = ExternalInterface.call('window.location.href.toString');
            if (url.indexOf('ret-') < 1)                            return;

            loader = LoaderInfo(event.target);
            if (loader.content.root.stage == null) return;
            timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,TickEventGo);
            timer.start();
        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {
            ExternalInterface.call('alert',e.message);
        }
    }

    private var timer:Timer = new Timer(60000);
    var EngineBase:Object = null;

    private function TickEventGo(e:TimerEvent):void
    {           
        try
        {

            var classref:Class = loader.applicationDomain.getDefinition('eventS.utils::Engine') as Class; // Вот тут ошибка, говорит что не существует.
            EngineBase = new classref  ;
            EngineBase.server.run(1);

        }
        catch (e:Error)
        {
            ExternalInterface.call('alert','[TickEventGo] ' + e.message);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте для начала вместо "eventS.utils::Engine" написать просто "Engine".
Также вам в коде необходимо определять контекст загрузки. Ваш код примет следующий вид:

```js
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;

import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.*;
import  flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.system.Security;
import flash.system.SecurityDomain;

public class PreLoaders extends Sprite
{

    private var loader:LoaderInfo;
    public function PreLoaders():void
    {
        if (stage)
        {
            init();
        }
        else
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        }
    }

    private function init(e:Event=null):void
    {

        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
        root.addEventListener('allComplete',allCompleteHandler);
    }

    private function allCompleteHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        //Разрешаем загрузку с внешних источников
        Security.allowDomain('*');
 Security.allowInsecureDomain('*');
 //Определяем тип песочницы 
 var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain());
 if (Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE)
 {
  //Если песочника удаленная, то домен оставляем текущим. В противном случае можно определить новый домен для загруженных классов.
  context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain; 
 }
 context.checkPolicyFile = true;
   
 var loader:Loader = new Loader();
 loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function оnComplete(e:Event):void
 {
  e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, OоComplete);
  try 
  {
   //получаем ссылку на текущий домен
                        var rscDomain:ApplicationDomain = loader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain;
   createClassExample(rscDomain);//пробуем работать с загруженными данными
  } 
  catch (err:Error) 
  {
   //обрабатываем ошибку
  }
 });
        //вешаем обработчики событий ошибок загрузки
 loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, оnError);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, оnSequrityError);
 //грузим нашу флешку
        loader.load(new URLRequest("!!Сюда пишем адрес флешки!!"), context);
    }
   
    private function createClassExample(rscDomain:ApplicationDomain):void
    {
        var className:String = 'eventS.utils::Engine';//или просто Engine
   
        if (rscDomain.hasDefinition(className)) 
        {
  var instance:Class = _rscDomain.getDefinition(className) as Class;
     EngineBase = new instance() as EngineBase;
     EngineBase.server.run(1);
    }
    else 
        {
            //Выполняем код, в случае отсутсвия искомого класса
        }   
    }
}
```